# Missing module when compiling python to exe

Tags: python

I am getting an error when compiling python to exe. the error is showing a missing module but when I install, the pip cannot find it. How can I install those modules?

> The following modules appear to be missing:
>   ['_scproxy', 'email.Encoders', 'email.MIMEBase', 'win32evtlog', 'win32evtlogutil']

*** binary dependencies ***

> Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included, USER32.DLL
>   you may or may not need to distribute them.

Comment: is your python script working ok before compiling to exe? If working, no need to pip. And, "email" should be standard library. Are you using py2exe or cx_freeze or pyinstaller?

Comment: i'm using py2exe to compile the working program yes...if the email should be standard why does it generate errors?

Comment: sometime even standard library is not packaged by py2exe. but you can explicitly include them through py2exe options. for example i had to manually include xml package. if you are not familiar with py2exe options, I would recommend GUI2EXE which provide GUI interface to many of these package tools.

Comment: Do you know ow to explicitly includes them through py2exe options?

Answer (score 0):

modified from the example at the bottom here : http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

```
from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe

setup(
        windows=['yourscript.py'],
        options={
                "py2exe":{
                        "includes": ['_scproxy', 'email.Encoders', 'email.MIMEBase', 'win32evtlog', 'win32evtlogutil']
                }
        }
)
```

You could try this setup.py

But I personally use gui2exe to produce setup.py.

Comment: it does not work the codes it generate some errors..I will try to play with gui2exe tnx